# React-FilePond - how to allow for preloaded file and automatic processing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, filepond

I've got two places where a user can upload an avatar for their profile: Onboarding, and Account Settings. During Onboarding, the user of course will be uploading their image for the first time, and everything works perfectly. In Account Settings, I want to have that file preloaded (it's a url from Cloudinary), and then allow the user to remove and upload a new avatar.

```react
const [file, setFile] = useState<any>(
    data?.me?.image ? buildImageSrc(data.me.image) : null
  );

const handleUpdateAvatar = async () => {
  console.log('handleUpdateAvatar');
};

...

<FilePond
  files={file}
  allowImageCrop
  allowImagePreview
  allowImageResize
  allowImageTransform
  imagePreviewMaxFileSize="2MB"
  onupdatefiles={files => {
    console.log({ files });  // <-- Runs twice on page load due to file preload
  }}
  maxFiles={1}
  name="avatar-upload"
  labelIdle="Drag & Drop your picture<br/>or <span class='filepond--label-action'>Browse</span>"
  acceptedFileTypes={['image/png', 'image/jpeg']}
  imagePreviewHeight={170}
  imageCropAspectRatio="1:1"
  imageResizeTargetHeight={250}
  imageResizeTargetWidth={250}
  stylePanelLayout="compact circle"
  styleLoadIndicatorPosition="center bottom"
  styleButtonRemoveItemPosition="center bottom"
/>
```

As you can see, I'm setting the user's file in state, which successfully preloads their avatar into the Filepond component. The issue now however, is that I'm unable to figure out when to trigger the `handleUpdateAvatar` function. You can see the console log for the `onupdatefiles` prop, and that console log gets triggered twice upon page load because of the url preload. If I run the function in `onupdatefiles`, it'd trigger that function twice right off the bat, which I don't want.

What I'm wanting, is a way to only trigger the update function once the user has removed their existing avatar, then uploaded a new one. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Use the `server` property to configure uploading/removing of files? https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/

Comment: @Rik not sure that'd work... I submit to a graphql endpoint

Comment: You can supply a custom process function which receives file and methods to update the interface, you can then basically do anything with the file you want.